# Context switching not happening between a created thread and main thread

Tags: multithreading, groovy

I am trying to run a thread in background with while(true) condition, and not using any join after the thread so that it continue running the main thread. But what I am observing is only while loop is running and it is not switching to main thread. please help me find the issue. This is Groovy code.

```
 public static void main(args) {
         Thread.start {
            while (true) {
                long sleepMillis = 2000  
                System.out.println("inside async block")
                Thread.sleep(sleepMillis)
            }
        }
  //main func code goes here
  }
```

Please give me pointers to the issue.

Comment: That should work... You sure it's what you're using?

Comment: Yes it worked. Issue was with the output i was looking at.

Comment: Could you maybe post the output? In your example, you only print out in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
public class Lol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        def t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    println 'lol'
                    Thread.sleep(500)
                }
            }
        }).start()
        println 'other'
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `join` before even starting the thread?

Comment: adding join will wait for the thread to finish right? My requirement is for the thread to work in background.

Comment: @MeenalGoyal is it ok now?

Comment: @cfrick, yes it is :)

Comment: Changing the syntax did not help. Somehow functions are not getting called.

Comment: Hmm.. Provide an example that reproduces the problem then. I thought it was `join` problem.

Comment: @MeenalGoyal thats because it's basically the same.  maybe the problem lies in the code after the thread?  have you put some printlns here and there?

Comment: Yes I have put quite few log statements, will try putting some more

Comment: Where did you put it? I can't see them in the question you asked.

Comment: //main func code goes here... is basically a placeholder for the code in my actual function.

Comment: That all should be ok. Maybe You're looking at the bad console output?

Comment: yes looks like this only. Trying to direct the output to a file and go through it.